# How to control that cancel the post of "likes?

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

while Using android-facebook api,

I got one question !

In short,

How to control that cancel the post of "likes?

Comment: You mean you want add "unlike" functionality?

Comment: I don't think you can control what the user likes and unlikes